# UI only updates after loop completes

Tags: jquery

I'm using `html()` in a loop. The display is only updated at the end of the loop. I added `console.log` after and I see the log in my console. If I add an `alert` I can see the display changing.

```js
for (i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
  $("#selector").html(" Occurences " + i);
  console.log(" Occurences " + i);
  //alert("something");
  wait(200);
}


function wait(ms) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  var end = start;
  while (end < start + ms) {
    end = new Date().getTime();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="selector">Test</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bhfnaxgk/3/

Comment: I used that in .each() en count word to replace by html element (input or texteara). The counter don't increase by one each time.

Comment: In summary: while your code is *running*, no other code can run and that includes UI updates.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behaviour as `for` and `while` loops blocks the UI from updating while they are being processed.

Assuming from the context of the code you're attempting to make an incremental counter which is shown in the UI you can use jQuery's `animate()` method:

```js
$({
  Counter: 0
}).animate({
  Counter: 25
}, {
  duration: 5000, // 25 iterations * 200ms delay
  easing: 'linear',
  step: n => $('#my_selector').text(`Occurences: ${Math.ceil(n)}`)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="my_selector"></span>
```

Comment: I used that in .each() en count word to replace by html element (input or texteara). The counter don't increase by one each time.

Comment: In that case can you please add a more representative example of your complete code (including HTML, CSS and JS) to the question

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sy2xd1wz/ Part of html code et js